# Inequality involving absolute value: $|x-1|>2-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How does one go about solving the following inequality?

$$|x-1|>2-x$$

Comment: Draw the graphs of $f(x)=|x-1|$ and $g(x)=2-x$ and the answer will become obvious.

Comment: Yes but how do I solve it algebraically? @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: Can you solve the inequalities $x-1>2-x$ and $1-x>2-x$? Consider that $|x-1|$ can be only $x-1$ or $1-x$, according to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-if $x - 1 \geq 0$ ($x \geq 1$), then $\vert x - 1 \vert = x - 1$, implies $x - 1 > 2- x$ which gives $x > \frac{3}{2}$.

-if $x - 1 \leq 0$ ($x \leq 1$), then $\vert x - 1 \vert = 1 - x$, implies $1 - x > 2- x$, which admits no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For an algebraic solution you can divide the inequality in two systems:
$$
\begin{cases}
x-1\ge 0\\
x-1>2-x  
\end{cases}
\quad \land \quad
\begin{cases}
x-1< 0\\
1-x>2-x  
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please, fix the "square" part, which is wrong. It gives the right solution just by chance.

Comment: Still wrong, I'm afraid. If $x>2$, the inequality is certainly satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

: Given inequality : $|x-1|>2-x$  \, there can obtain two possible solutions of any absolute value inequality, because the expression inside the absolute value sign can be positive and negative. 
Thus, there are two cases, (1) $x-1>2-x$ and (2) $x-1>-(2-x)$

Case-1: $x-1>2-x$

$\implies$ $x-1+x>2$

$\implies$ $2x>2+1$

$\implies$ $2x>3$

$\implies$ $x>3/2$

Case-2: $x-1>-(2-x)$

$\implies$ $x-1>-2+x$

$\implies$ $x-1-x>-2$

$\implies$ $0>-2+1$

$\implies$ $0>-1$

It means there is no solution in Case-2.

Thus, there is only positive value possible inside the absolute value sign for this given inequality and only one solution that is $x>3/2.$

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique for solving inequalities called the "split point method", which doesn't require so much "parity chasing."  The method is:  1.  Solve the corresponding equation and find all discontinuities.  These are the "split points."  2.  Plot the split points on a number line.  This cuts the line into a number of intervals.  Each of these intervals is either part of the solution set or not.  3.  Test each interval by choosing a nice point in the *interior* of each interval.  If the one point makes the inequality true, then the whole interval does.  Otherwise not.  Test each split point separately.

So solve $\mid x-1 \mid = 2-x$.  Either $x-1 = 2-x$ and so $x=3/2$ or $-(x-1) = 2-x$ which has no solution.  There are no disconinutites, so there is only one split point.  Plot $x=3/2$ on the number line. To test the interval $(-\infty,3/2)$ plug $0$ into the inequality for $x$ to get $\mid 0-1 \mid > 2-0$.  This is false, so that interval is not part of the solution set.  To test the interval $(3/2,\infty)$ plug $2$ in for $x$ to get $\mid 2-1 \mid >2-2$ which is true.  So that interval is part of the solution set.  The value $x=3/2$ makes the inequality false.  So the solution set is $(3/2,\infty)$.

The reason this works is that you've found all the points where the graph of the right hand side minus the left hand side can cross the $x$-axis.